# linux-modules-extra-4.15.0-59-generic needs to be reinstalled but can't find an archive for it

Tags: package-management, upgrade, kernel

I am running ubuntu 18.04.3 LTS. For last few days I am getting this error "linux-modules-extra-4.15.0-59-generic needs to be reinstalled but can't find an archive for it" whenever I check for software updates from "Settings->Details->Check for updates"

I have tried the following from the terminal but am getting the same message

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get upgrade
```

This throws an error "The package linux-modules-extra-4.15.0-59-generic needs to be reinstalled but I can't find an archive for it".

I tried

```
sudo apt-get install --reinstall linux-modules-extra-4.15.0-59-generic
```

Still the same error

I also tried

```
sudo apt-get install -f linux-modules-extra-4.15.0-59-generic
```

Still the same error

Thus no software updates are getting installed

Comment: The information available at https://www.ubuntuupdates.org/package/core/bionic/main/proposed/linux-modules-extra-4.15.0-59-generic   Package "linux-modules-extra-4.15.0-59-generic"

WARNING: the "linux-modules-extra-4.15.0-59-generic" package was deleted from this repository


Name: linux-modules-extra-4.15.0-59-generic

Description: 
Linux kernel extra modules for version 4.15.0 on 32 bit x86 SMP

Latest version: *DELETED*
Release: bionic (18.04)
Level: proposed
Repository: main
Head package: linux